# How to ignore case while doing most_common in Python's collections.Counter?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, python-collections

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of an element in an iterable using `most_common` in the `collections` module.

```
>>> names = ['Ash', 'ash', 'Aish', 'aish', 'Juicy', 'juicy']
>>> Counter(names).most_common(3)
[('Juicy', 1), ('juicy', 1), ('ash', 1)]
```

But what I expect is,

```
[('juicy', 2), ('ash', 2), ('aish', 2)]
```

Is there a "pythonic" way/trick to incorporate the **'ignore-case'** functionality , so that we can get the desired output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about mapping it to `str.lower`?

```
>>> Counter(map(str.lower, names)).most_common(3)
[('juicy', 2), ('aish', 2), ('ash', 2)]
```